# Ensuring that a combination of records in a many to many relationship is unique

Tags: postgresql, many-to-many

We want to enforce that a combination of an entity is unique in a join table.

Suppose we have the following many to many relationship between `widgets` and `combinations`

```
widgets
-------
widget_id
w1        
w2

combinations
------------
combination_id
c1
c2

widgets_combinations
--------------------
widget_id combination_id
w1         c1
w2         c1
w1         c2
```

We can easily ensure that no relationship between widget and combination appears more than once with a uniqueness constraint on (widget_id, combination_id) on `widgets_combinations`.

But do we ensure that no two combinations have the same set of widgets?

The example above would be valid, as `c1={w1,w2}` and `c2={w1}` - they are unique sets

However, if we add the row `(w2, c2)` to the join table, we get this invalid configuration.

```
widgets_combinations
--------------------
widget_id combination_id
w1         c1
w2         c1
w1         c2
w2         c2
```

c1 and c2 are no longer unique sets of widgets. `c1={w1,w2}` and `c2={w1,w2}`. How might we prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I can think of is not pretty.

You would denormalize your data model by adding another column to `combinations`:

```
/* use the array type that belongs to the data type of "widget_id" */
ALTER TABLE combinations ADD all_widgets text[] DEFAULT ARRAY[];
```

Then you need an `INSERT` trigger like

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_combination_widgets() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql SET search_path = 'appschema' AS
$$BEGIN
   UPDATE combinations
   SET all_widgets = (SELECT array_agg(wc.widget_id ORDER BY wc.widget_id)
                      FROM widgets_combinations AS wc
                      WHERE wc.combination_id = NEW.combination_id)
   WHERE combination_id = NEW.combination_id;

   RETURN NEW;
END$$;

CREATE TRIGGER update_combination_widgets AFTER INSERT ON widgets_combinations
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION update_combination_widgets();
```

You have to initialize the new column with

```
UPDATE combinations SET all_widgets = agg.w_ids
FROM (SELECT combination_id AS c_id,
             array_agg(widget_id ORDER BY widget_id) AS w_ids
      FROM widgets_combinations
      GROUP BY combination_id) AS agg
WHERE combinations.combination_id = agg.c_id;
```

Now you can create a simple constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE combinations ADD UNIQUE (all_widgets);
```

Due to the limitation on the size of index entries, this will only work if the array are not too large.

Comment: Sorry if I am misunderstanding something in the answer, but shouldn't the unique contraint on combinations be on `all_widgets` only so that a combination is unique across all combinations? Also, since the trigger runs after each insert, couldn't this trigger the unique constraint before all widgets in a combination have been inserted? For instance, if combination (c1 => [w1]) already exists and we're trying to insert combination (c2 => [w1,w2]), after we insert the row (c2,w1), wouldn't this trigger the unique constraint right away? Thanks!

Comment: @sowee15 You are right; my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

For Postgres, I imagine you would use a statement-level *after* [trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) if you can ensure all changes to a combination happen in a single statement, for example:

```
-- Complete combo specified in a single statement
INSERT INTO widgets_combinations
    (widget_id, combination_id)
VALUES
    ('w1', 'c1'),
    ('w2', 'c2'),
    ('w1', 'c2'),
    ('w2', 'c2');
```

If you need separate statements, make the changes within a transaction and enforce the condition you need in an [`INITIALLY DEFERRED`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) *constraint trigger* so the check is performed when the transaction commits.

I don't know Postgres well enough to write a complete example, but the following is for SQL Server in case it is useful. SQL Server doesn't support deferred constraints, so this implementation uses a statement-level after trigger:

[*db<>fiddle* online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/aokIltJP)

#### Tables

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Widget 
(
    WidgetName char(2) NOT NULL

    CONSTRAINT [PK dbo.Widget WidgetName]
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (WidgetName)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.WidgetCombo 
(
    WidgetCombo char(2) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK dbo.WidgetCombo WidgetCombo]
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (WidgetCombo)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.WidgetComboMember 
(
    WidgetCombo char(2) NOT NULL,
    WidgetName char(2) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK dbo.WidgetComboMember WidgetCombo, WidgetName]
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (WidgetCombo, WidgetName),

    CONSTRAINT [FK dbo.WidgetComboMember WidgetCombo]
        FOREIGN KEY (WidgetCombo)
            REFERENCES dbo.WidgetCombo (WidgetCombo),

    CONSTRAINT [FK dbo.WidgetComboMember Widget]
        FOREIGN KEY (WidgetName)
            REFERENCES dbo.Widget (WidgetName),

    CONSTRAINT [UQ dbo.WidgetComboMember WidgetName, WidgetCombo]
        UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (WidgetName, WidgetCombo)
);
```

#### Trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.UniqueWidgetCombos
ON dbo.WidgetComboMember
AFTER INSERT AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE
    @ConflictCombos varchar(max),
    @WidgetNames varchar(max);

-- Find dupicates
-- READCOMMITTEDLOCK hints needed because we can't use MVCC
-- when checking constraints. Must read the latest data and
-- block on lock conflict.
SELECT
    @ConflictCombos = GC.ConflictCombos, 
    @WidgetNames = GC.WidgetNames
FROM 
(
    -- Combos affected by this insert
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        I.WidgetCombo 
    FROM Inserted AS I
) AS ToCheck
-- Check each combo for conflicts
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT
        ConflictCombos =
            STRING_AGG(CONVERT(varchar(max), WidgetComboNames.WidgetCombo), ',')
                WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY WidgetComboNames.WidgetCombo),
        WidgetComboNames.WidgetNames
    FROM 
    (
        -- All interesting combos with their member lists
        SELECT
            M1.WidgetCombo,
            WidgetNames = 
                STRING_AGG(CONVERT(varchar(max), M1.WidgetName), ',') 
                    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY M1.WidgetName)
        FROM 
        (
            -- All combos sharing at least one member with the combo we're checking
            SELECT DISTINCT
                M2.WidgetCombo
            FROM dbo.WidgetComboMember AS M3
                WITH (READCOMMITTEDLOCK)
            JOIN dbo.WidgetComboMember AS M2
                WITH (READCOMMITTEDLOCK)
                ON M2.WidgetName = M3.WidgetName
            WHERE
                M3.WidgetCombo = ToCheck.WidgetCombo
        ) AS Q1
        JOIN dbo.WidgetComboMember AS M1
            WITH (READCOMMITTEDLOCK)
            ON M1.WidgetCombo = Q1.WidgetCombo
        GROUP BY 
            M1.WidgetCombo
    ) AS WidgetComboNames
    GROUP BY 
        WidgetComboNames.WidgetNames
    -- Conflict if the same list of members occurs for more than one combo
    HAVING
        COUNT_BIG(*) > 1
) AS GC
OPTION (FORCE ORDER);

IF @ConflictCombos IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage nvarchar(2048) = 
        CONCAT
        (
            N'Insert resulted in duplicate widget combos: ', 
            @ConflictCombos,
            N' with widget names: ',
            @WidgetNames);

    -- Roll back the insert and report an error
    THROW 50000, @ErrorMessage, 1;
END;
```

#### Reference data

```
INSERT dbo.Widget 
    (WidgetName) 
VALUES 
    ('w1'), 
    ('w2'),
    ('w3');

INSERT dbo.WidgetCombo 
    (WidgetCombo) 
VALUES 
    ('c1'), 
    ('c2');
```

#### Tests

```
-- Error
INSERT dbo.WidgetComboMember 
    (WidgetCombo, WidgetName) 
VALUES 
    ('c1', 'w1'), 
    ('c1', 'w2'),
    ('c2', 'w1'),
    ('c2', 'w2');

-- Succeeds
INSERT dbo.WidgetComboMember 
    (WidgetCombo, WidgetName) 
VALUES 
    ('c1', 'w1'), 
    ('c1', 'w2'),
    ('c2', 'w1'),
    ('c2', 'w3'),
    ('c2', 'w2');
```