# Search for a record which has an exact set of many-to-many related records

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, many-to-many

I have a straightforward many-many arrangement:

### scans

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

### products

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

### product_scan:

| scan_id | product_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |

When I'm about to create a new scan entry with a proposed set of products, I want to know if there is already a scan record linked to an identical set of products, to avoid duplicates. So if I have a new scan that wants to link to products 1 and 2, it needs to match scan 1, *but not scan 2* . Similarly a new scan with products 1, 2, and 3 would match scan 2, but not scan 1, and a scan with products 2 and 3 would not match either of the existing scans (i.e. not a duplicate). This list of possible products linked to a scan is arbitrary and of variable length and random order, so I can't use hard-coded values in the query.

I've been trying all kinds of weird queries involving subqueries and `having` clauses, doing things like finding all related record that match the provided IDs and counting the matches, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to exclude records that are a superset of the requested list. I've now reached a point where I'm generating subqueries in a loop, and it's not pretty, and still doesn't work. I have found some answers like [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/321048/ensuring-that-a-combination-of-records-in-a-many-to-many-relationship-is-unique), which is the stuff of nightmares...

Is there a simple way to do this search?

Comment: [_Many-to-many_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) makes the table more efficient and forces uniqueness.

Comment: That's not what I asked; I'm looking for searching on these IDs, not preventing their existence. I already have a unique (primary) key on the join table to prevent the same product being attached to a scan more than once, but that has no bearing on this problem.